# Value starting with a "Space" in HttpURLConnection.add Request Property?

Tags: http, http-headers, httpurlconnection

This is the code in the client: 
`connection.addRequestProperty("key", value);`
This is the code in the server :

```
String user=req.getHeader("key");
System.out.println(user);
```

If the value is, for eg, `"abcd xyz"` in the client, printed value in the server is the same. But if the value is `" abcd xyz"`, the value printed in the server is `"abcd xyz"` i,e the starting space is not there. 
What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTTP header field values, leading and trailing whitespace is not significant. Thus, they will be gone after parsing.

Comment: where is the space is removed - before transmission? Is there any documentation that talks about this?

Comment: It might be before or upon reception. And yes, the HTTP spec defines this.